# Allow users to add items to their profiles Mongoose

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean

I am building a mean stack app with express and mongoose. I have two schemas, userSchema and courseSchema:

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
          Schema = mongoose.Schema;    
    var courseSchema = mongoose.Schema({
      title:{type:String, required:'{PATH} is required!'},
      featured:{type:Boolean, required:'{PATH} is required!'},
      published:{type:Date, required:'{PATH} is required!'},
      courseLink:{type:String, required:'{PATH} is required!'},
      user: [{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'User'}]

    });

var Course = mongoose.model('Course', courseSchema);

module.exports = Course;

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        firstName: {type: String, required: true},
        lastName: {type: String, required: true},
        username: {
                    type: String,
                    required: true,
                    unique: true    // creates unique index inside MongoDB          
        },
        salt: {type: String, required: true},
        hashed_pwd: {type: String, required: true},
        roles:[String],
        courses:[{type: Schema.ObjectId, 
                 ref: 'Course' }]
    });
```

I am able to create users and and courses (as an admin). What I want to do now is to allow each user add a course to his list of courses (or just click a 'like' button beside the course and that course would be added to his profile).

On the side of the controller, I have tried to check for the user id from the session, find that user and add the course to his document. But that's where I am stuck,

```
exports.addMyCourse = function(req, res){
  console.log('user id', req.session.passport.user);
  console.log('id', req.body._id);
    var currentUserId = req.session.passport.user;

    User.findOne({'_id':currentUserId}, function(err, doc){
        console.log(doc);
  });
```

Most of the solutions I looked at are not very clear about this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED:

I used $addToSet to add the course objects into the courses array inside the User model:

This might be useful for people searching for similar soutions:

My User schema:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

        firstName: {type: String, required: true},
        lastName: {type: String, required: true},
        username: {
                    type: String,
                    required: true,
                    unique: true    // creates unique index inside MongoDB          
        },
        salt: {type: String, required: true},
        hashed_pwd: {type: String, required: true},
        roles:[String],
        courses:[{
            type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:'Course'
        }]
    });
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

My Course schema:
    var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
          Schema = mongoose.Schema;

```
var courseSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title:{type:String, required:'{PATH} is required!'},
  featured:{type:Boolean, required:'{PATH} is required!'},
  published:{type:Date, required:'{PATH} is required!'},
  courseLink:{type:String, required:'{PATH} is required!'}
});    

var Course = mongoose.model('Course', courseSchema);
```

Inside my controllers folder, I have users.js and courses.js:

In the courses.js file, I created the addMyCourses middleware to update the User model's courses array by first retrieving the current user's id from the session and using $addToSet to insert the object and avoid duplicates at the same time. Also I made sure I am adding only the ObjectId's of the courses and not the entire course document so I won't have future problems with too much data in one document:

```
exports.addMyCourse = function(req, res){
  var myCourse = {
        title: req.body.title,
        featured: req.body.featured,
        published: req.body.published,
        courseLink: req.body.courseLink
  };

  var currentUserId = req.session.passport.user;   

  var courseId = req.body._id;

  User.update({_id:currentUserId},
        {$addToSet: {"courses": courseId}},
        {safe: true, upsert: true, new : true},
        function(err, model) {
            console.log(model);
        }
    );
};
```

Since I only had the ObjectId's of the courses inside the courses array of the User model, I had to use mongoose's populate() method to do a joint query on both models so that I get the corresponding course documents of the ids.

In users.js file:

```
exports.getUserCourses = function(req, res, next){
      var currentUserId = req.session.passport.user; 
  User.findById(currentUserId).populate('courses')
    .exec(function(err, data){
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
      } 
      console.log('user courses', data);
      res.send(data);
    })
  };
```